# google maps gives results not returned by google places API or google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to find the lat/long of the Sydney Opera House using either the Google maps API or the Google Places API.  But neither return anything like it, despite the fact that Google Maps from the browser instantly finds the correct result.

I'm using these URL's:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&bounds=-28.729,153.984|-36.102,142.470&address=OPERA%20HOUSE

and

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.9179,151.2333&radius=5000&sensor=false&name=opera%20house&key={secret}

Google Maps API returns 3 places in China & USA, and Google Places API returns "ZERO_RESULTS". You'll excuse me for not including my Google Places key.  The lat/long are for central Sydney.

Am I doing something wrong, or does Google Maps use a private database which is more complete than the database the API's use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies everyone, in fact I was doing something wrong:  the (lat,lng) is for Kensington which is more than 5km from the Opera House, so it's outside the radius.  When I increase the radius, I get the expected results.

In other words, I have no evidence that the Google Places API provides worse results than the Google Maps web page.

Note: Adding "NSW" to the end of a Google *Maps* API query results in the opera house being found.

Comment: Can you explain specifically what you mean by `Note: Adding "NSW" to the end of a Google Maps API query results in the opera house being found.`? Is that a new querystring parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Sydney Opera House](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&bounds=-28.729,153.984|-36.102,142.470&address=Sydney+OPERA%20HOUSE)?

EDIT: or the new [keyword search](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/05/google-places-api-search-refinements-as.html)?

Comment: "Sydney Opera House" gives the desired result.  But I am concerned about my users who have a reasonable expectation that if they enter just "Opera House" and they're in Sydney, that our app understands what they mean.  Google Maps understands that, so why doesn't Google Maps/Places API?